# Property 'bind' does not exist on type 'void'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following code:

```
setInterval(this.CheckIfCameraIsAvailable(false).bind(this), 2 * 60 * 1000);

 private CheckIfCameraIsAvailable(forceCheck: boolean) {

}
```

I have the following error:

> Property 'bind' does not exist on type 'void'

The error will be solved when I remove (forceCheck: boolean) parameter from (CheckIfCameraIsAvailable) function, but I want to pass a parameter to the function.

Comment: You're trying to bind the result of calling the method, not the method. Why not use an arrow function `setInterval(() => this.CheckIfCameraIsAvailable(false), 2 * 60 * 1000)`?

Comment: Why the error will be solved when I remove (forceCheck: boolean) parameter from the function?

Comment: Because presumably then you're doing `this.CheckIfCameraIsAvailable.bind(this)`, without the parentheses, so *actually binding the method*. If you did `this.CheckIfCameraIsAvailable().bind(this)` you'd have the same problem. You need to pass a callable with no parameters to `setInterval`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you it is working when using the arrow function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your example, you are accidentally calling the function, and then trying to use `.bind` on the result. The correct long-hand code would be the following (where you pass the `false` argument as part of the `bind`:

```
class Example {
  CheckIfCameraIsAvailable(forceCheck: boolean) {
    alert(forceCheck);
  }

  run() {
    setInterval(this.CheckIfCameraIsAvailable.bind(this, false), 2000);
  }
}

const example = new Example();
example.run();
```

The short-hand way to preserve the lexical scope is to use an arrow function:

```
class Example {
  CheckIfCameraIsAvailable(forceCheck: boolean) {
    alert(forceCheck);
  }

  run() {
    setInterval(() => this.CheckIfCameraIsAvailable(false), 2000);
  }
}

const example = new Example();
example.run();
```

And this is the equivalent of introducing an intermediate variable like this:

```
class Example {
  CheckIfCameraIsAvailable(forceCheck: boolean) {
    alert(forceCheck);
  }

  run() {
    const _this = this;
    setInterval(function () { _this.CheckIfCameraIsAvailable(false) }, 2000);
  }
}

const example = new Example();
example.run();
```